# What hosting services can I use for a Django web app using postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, web-hosting

Can I use any hosting service?  I'm confused as to whether the type of database restricts the hosting services available.

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more (Here hosting services) is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm not asking for a recommendation.  My question is if what hosting service I can use is determined by the backend (Django) or the database (postgres).  For all I know, Django plus MySQL can be deployed to WAMP but Django plus postgres might not be supported.

Comment: It is still off-topic (and in a way still asking for recommendations / _finding hosting services_) as you basically ask for a list of hosting services you can use for Django plus Postgres which in the end would result in N answers listing different services (there are ***many***).

Comment: It's more about how does django handle these things.  I've looked online but can't find a clear explanation.  I knew I'd encounter the typical stack overflow snark but I thought I'd try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with heroku, AWS, or Gcloud but Aws and Gcloud have trial version, if you trying for fun and deploy your own projects then you can try with heroku since heroku use postgres database by default you don't have to do something, ref this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deploy-django-application-on-heroku/